# Why am I getting HTTP 400 bad request

Tags: java, post, httpclient

I am using an HTTP client (code copied from http://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/) to send post requests. I have been trying to use it with http://postcodes.io to look up a bulk of postcodes but failed. According to http://postcodes.io I should send a post request to http://api.postcodes.io/postcodes in the following JSON form: `{"postcodes" : ["OX49 5NU", "M32 0JG", "NE30 1DP"]}` but I am always getting HTTP Response Code 400.
I have included my code below. Please tell me what am I doing wrong?
Thanks

```
private void sendPost() throws Exception {

    String url = "http://api.postcodes.io/postcodes";
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

    List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("postcodes", "[\"OX49 5NU\", \"M32 0JG\", \"NE30 1DP\"]"));
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

    System.out.println("Response Code : " 
                + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    System.out.println("Reason : " 
            + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }
    br.close();
    System.out.println(result.toString());
}
```

Comment: I suspect the form of post you're using at the moment will be sending this as a form-url-encoded set of parameters, when you just want to post a body with the JSON in. I could be wrong, of course, but I suspect you don't want a UrlEncodedFormEntity at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works, HTTP.UTF_8 is deprecated:

```
String url = "http://api.postcodes.io/postcodes";
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

StringEntity params =new StringEntity("{\"postcodes\" : [\"OX49 5NU\", \"M32 0JG\", \"NE30 1DP\"]}");
post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
post.setEntity(params);
```

Comment: Great answer & Problem solved! I was missing the add header and didn't occur to me. Thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

Jon Skeet is right (as usual, I might add), you are basically sending a form and it defaults to form-url-encoding.
You could try something like this instead:

```
String jsonString = "{\"postcodes\" : [\"OX49 5NU\", \"M32 0JG\", \"NE30 1DP\"]}";
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonObj.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);
entity.setContentType("application/json");
post.setEntity(entity);
```

Comment: I agree with you, and I am using now StringEntity. I have tried this `String jsonString = "{\"postcodes\":[\"OX49 5NU\",\"M32 0JG\",\"NE30 1DP\"]}";
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(requestJSON.toString(), "UTF-8");
post.setEntity(entity);` which is as close as it gets to your code. I am still getting 400 but this time with more detailed explanation: _{"status":400,"error":"Invalid JSON submitted. You need to submit a JSON object with an array of postcodes or geolocation objects"}_